# How from Fourier Transform with imaginary numbers we get the one with real numbers?

Tags: fourier-transform

There is Fourier Transform formula with `e` pow `i`, there is also another Fourier Transform formula with real numbers only (with `sin` and `cos`).

I thought that imaginary numbers are imaginary only except for `e` pow `2pi` which is 0 and `e` pow `pi` which is 1.

How come that imaginary numbers become all of a sudden real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we have that
$$\sin{(x)}=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
$$\cos{(x)}=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
So the complex exponentials can be rewritten as sine and cosine.

Comment: Found your answer useful for my homework. Found that imaginary numbers are also 'like' "real" numbers since they are roots of -1. I realize now that the Hormonic Signal in Fourier representation is just same sin/cos with root of minus one now, that eases my mind. Many thanks, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've edited the Hebrew wiki site page, but since I'm not native English speaker, here's an explanation *in-here*:

As Peter, who has answered the question said, there is a formula that gives and provides for each Fourier in ${C}$, it's result in ${R}$. But in order to understand who's he do that, we'll need first to understand *how's the fourier function being built.*

Recall that -

${e^i}$ is a circle with radius ${1}$ .

Taking periodic ${f(x)}$ and having:

${e^{i{\omega}f(x)}}$

Would lead us to a function drawn 'over' circle with radius 1 whereas *each point on the circle would give us the point on the function, while the distance of ${f(t)}$ on the circle from the middle of the circle, is the height of ${f(t)}$ from ${Xt}$ axis*.

So to answer my own question, getting real numbers from $C$ dimension functions, is done by calculating distance (which is $R$), from the middle of the circle (which is simple expressed *using* - not *in* - *using* different dimensions).