# What is that $t$ in $E[e^{itX}]$?

Tags: statistics, characteristic-functions

I'm looking at the Characteristic Function Of A Random Variable. I don't understand why it's less than or equals to 1, since I see Mean Function on Random Variable ($E[e^{iX}]$), which might be bigger than 1. And t, which I don't understand in the first place is my 1st suspect.
Could someone explain me the role of that $t$?

Referring to my latest comment after research on my own question, on *How do the complex functions get built* (here: [How from Fourier Transform with imaginary numbers we get the one with real numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338362/how-from-fourier-transform-with-imaginary-numbers-we-get-the-one-with-real-numbe/3381000#3381000) ).

Comment: Hi me, I'd being reading this after a while and my core misunderstanding was that I was referring to the value inside E to be bigger than 1. It's okay, but f_X is smaller than 1 hence E is also 'okay'. t is anonymous value, it's important for us at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from two facts:

1. $\left|E[X]\right| \leq E[|X|]$ for any complex-valued random $X$
2. If $x$ is a real number, then $\left|e^{ix}\right| = 1$

In particular, this means $\left|E[e^{iX}]\right| \leq 1$ cannot be larger than $1$ when $X$ is real-valued.

As for your later question, the $t$ allows us to see the characteristic as a function of $t,$ so we may, among other things, integrate the characteristic function (e.g. the inverse transform) and differentiate the characteristic function (e.g. to find moments)

Comment: But the distance of x from the axis is going and becomes larger, then how come the distance of point on $e^{ix}$ from the middle of the circle is 1? I'm confused. And thank you, kindly, for your answer!!

Comment: We have the identity $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ and if $x$ is a real number, $$|e^{ix}| = \sqrt{\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)} = \sqrt{1} = 1$$
In other words, the real number $x$ in $e^{ix}$ is actually just the angle for a point on the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! You convinced me. Regarding the circle with rdius 1 problem, I'll research it and see how does it work.

Comment: Brian I apologies I disturb you again, I tried to look for the answer for the whole day but found none. How does it settle with that, that $|e^{if(t)}|$ should be equal to $f(t)$? Like, I understand what you said, I don't understand how to wrap the graph around the circle properly.

Comment: I understood eventually!! :D Answering to myself in the question if needed.