# How to wrap $f(x)=x$ around the singular circle properly?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function, fourier-series

I was watching this video: https://youtu.be/spUNpyF58BY

About Fourier Series, which explained we can wrap a graph around a circle to get a form of $e^{if(t)}$ to have $|e^{if(t)}|=f(t)$, I give a reference to my explanation in here:

[How from Fourier Transform with imaginary numbers we get the one with real numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338362/how-from-fourier-transform-with-imaginary-numbers-we-get-the-one-with-real-numbe)

I tried to wrap $f(x)=x$ around a circle, and I assumed that the answer to $|e^{...}|$ would be $x$. Because we wrap $f(x)=x$ around the circle. But I was wrong, $|e^{ix}|$ is $1$.

Why? Why is that? How can we wrap ANY graph around a circle to get the correct result, what's the proper way to do so?

EDIT: I found the following link, but it's off topic and talks only about programmatically doing the plot: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64534/how-to-wrap-a-plot-around-a-circle

Answer (score 1):

*Dear me...*

The wrapping is true for periodic function. In your example a period of $1$ is hidden. At $t=1$, $f(1)$ equals $1$, hence indeed still it is true and WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get).